# How do I add a column to a dataframe based on values from other columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I would like to add a column based on the values of the other columns

If the problem were only that, I think a good solution would be [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46684122/4451521)
However my problem is a bit more complicated

Say I have

```
import pandas as pd
a= pd.DataFrame([[5,6],[1,2],[3,6],[4,1]],columns=['a','b'])
print(a)
```

I have

```
   a  b
0  5  6
1  1  2
2  3  6
3  4  1
```

Now I want to add a column called 'result' where each of the values would be the result of applying this function

```
def process(a,b,c,d):
    return {"notthisone":2*a,
            "thisone":(a*b+c*d),
            }
```

to each of the rows and the next rows of the dataframe

This function is part of a library, it outputs two values but we are only interested in the values of the key `thisone`
Also, if possible we can not decompose the operations of the function but we have to apply it to the values

For example in the first row
`a=5,b=6,c=1,d=2` (c and d being the a and b of the next rows) and we want to add the value "thisone" so `5*6+1*2=32`

In the end I will have

```
   a  b  result
0  5  6   32
1  1  2   20
2  3  6   22
3  4  1   22 --> This is an special case since there is no next row so just a repeat of the previous would be fine
```

How can I do this?

I am thinking of traversing the dataframe with a loop but there must be a better and faster way...

EDIT:

I have done this so far

```
def p4(a,b):
    return {"notthisone":2*a,
            "thisone":(a*b),
            }

print(a.apply(lambda row: p4(row.a,row.b)["thisone"], axis=1))
```

and the result is

```
0    30
1     2
2    18
3     4
dtype: int64
```

So now I have to think of a way to incorporate next row values too

Comment: Does the function always need only the values of the next row?

Comment: @evces yes, it does. In the last row, I suppose some special thing would be needed but I am not thinking about that yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the values of the very next row, I think it would be best to shift these values back into the current row (with different column names). Then they can all be accessed by row-wise `apply(fn, axis=1)`.

```
# library function
def process(a, b, c, d):
    return {
        "notthisone": 2 * a,
        "thisone": (a * b + c * d),
    }

# toy data
df = pd.DataFrame([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0], [7.0, 8.0]], columns=["a", "b"])
# shift some data back one row
df[["c", "d"]] = df[["a", "b"]].shift(-1)
# apply your function row-wise
df["result"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: process(x["a"], x["b"], x["c"], x["d"])["thisone"], axis=1
)
```

Result:

```
    a   b   c   d   result
0   1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 14.0
1   3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 42.0
2   5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0 86.0
3   7.0 8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use loc accessor to select the rows, turn them into a numpy object and find the product and sum. I used list squares in this case. Last row will be Null. fillna the resulting column. We can fillna at the df level but that could impact other columns if the df is large and has nulls. Code below.

```
a = a.assign(x=pd.Series([np.prod(a.iloc[x].to_numpy()) + np.prod(a.iloc[x+1].to_numpy()) for x in np.arange(len(a)) if x!=len(a)-1]))
a =a.assign(x=a['x'].ffill())



    a   b   x
0   5   6   32.0
1   1   2   20.0
2   3   6   22.0
3   4   1   22.0
```